# sharing SharePoint calendar with document library

Tags: document-library, calendar

Is it possible to use the calendar to show expiry dates for the document library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

- Go to the **List settings**
- In the bottom of the page you will get **create view**
- Select "**Calendar view**" on type
- Then select the columns you wants to use in calendar